# Use selenium to write in and run a code cell in jupyterlab

Tags: python, selenium, codemirror, jupyter-lab

I would like to test a patched implementation of juptyerlab. I was hoping to use selenium to execute `"hello world"` in a code cell. So far I can log in and create a new notebook:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# assume jupyterlab is running and serving on localhost at port 8888
driver.get("http://localhost:8888")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("password_input")
password = ""
elem.send_keys(password)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("login_submit")
elem.click()
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".jp-Launcher-cwd+ .jp-Launcher-section .jp-LauncherCard")
elem.click()
```

This creates a new notebook, but now I'm stuck at the point of entering some code in a cell and running it. If I view the page source I don't see any html elements for the cells. But if I enter `print("test")` in a cell, then `driver.page_source` contains this (it's pretty nested in other stuff I've omitted too):

```
                                <div class="CodeMirror cm-s-jupyter CodeMirror-wrap jp-mod-readOnly">
                                    <div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 3px; height: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
                                        <textarea
                                                style="position: absolute; bottom: -1em; padding: 0px; width: 1px; height: 1em; outline: currentcolor none medium;"
                                                autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off"
                                                spellcheck="false" tabindex="0"
                                                wrap="off"></textarea></div>
                                    <div class="CodeMirror-vscrollbar" tabindex="-1"
                                         cm-not-content="true"
                                         style="display: block; bottom: 0px;">
                                        <div style="min-width: 1px; height: 33px;"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="CodeMirror-hscrollbar" tabindex="-1"
                                         cm-not-content="true">
                                        <div style="height: 100%; min-height: 1px; width: 0px;"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="CodeMirror-scrollbar-filler"
                                         cm-not-content="true"></div>
                                    <div class="CodeMirror-gutter-filler"
                                         cm-not-content="true"></div>
                                    <div class="CodeMirror-scroll" tabindex="-1" draggable="true">
                                        <div class="CodeMirror-sizer"
                                             style="margin-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                                            <div style="position: relative;">
                                                <div class="CodeMirror-lines" role="presentation">
                                                    <div style="position: relative; outline: currentcolor none medium;"
                                                         role="presentation">
                                                        <div class="CodeMirror-measure">
                                                            <pre><span>xxxxxxxxxx</span></pre>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="CodeMirror-measure">
                                                            <pre class="CodeMirror-line"
                                                                 role="presentation"><span
                                                                    role="presentation"><span
                                                                    class="cm-builtin">print</span>(<span
                                                                    class="cm-string">"test"</span>)</span></pre>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div style="position: relative; z-index: 1;"></div>
                                                        <div class="CodeMirror-cursors"></div>
                                                        <div class="CodeMirror-code"
                                                             role="presentation"></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="position: absolute; height: 30px; width: 1px; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;"></div>
                                        <div class="CodeMirror-gutters"
                                             style="display: none;"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

I can see where the text for `print("text")` is (i.e. the deepest nested elements in the above html snippet), but I can't figure out which element here I would be able to send text to or send keys to.

I came across [robotframework-jupyterlibrary](https://github.com/robots-from-jupyter/robotframework-jupyterlibrary) and it has some clues such as [this](https://github.com/robots-from-jupyter/robotframework-jupyterlibrary/blob/master/src/JupyterLibrary/clients/jupyterlab/Selectors.robot) and [this](https://github.com/robots-from-jupyter/robotframework-jupyterlibrary/blob/master/src/JupyterLibrary/clients/jupyterlab/Notebook.robot) . From those links I see

```
${JLAB CSS ACTIVE INPUT} ${JLAB CSS ACTIVE CELL} .CodeMirror
```

and

```
Add and Run JupyterLab Code Cell
    [Arguments]    ${code}=print("hello world")
    [Documentation]    Add a ``code`` cell to the currently active notebook and run it.
    Click Element    css:${JLAB CSS NB TOOLBAR} ${JLAB CSS ICON ADD}
    Sleep    0.1s
    ${cell} =   Get WebElement  css:${JLAB CSS ACTIVE INPUT}
    Click Element    ${cell}
    Set CodeMirror Value    ${JLAB CSS ACTIVE INPUT}  ${code}
    Run Current JupyterLab Code Cell
Click Element ${cell}
```

which makes me think if I select the `.CodeMirror` element, then I just need to figure out what `Get WebElement` does in that weird language and how to do it in selenium.

Any ideas?

---

I've also tried (based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/48723135/1011724 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/50279295/1011724):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
textarea = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.CodeMirror textarea')[0]  # tried for [0], [1] ,[2] and [3] which is all of them.
actions.move_to_element(textarea).click().send_keys("testing...").perform()
```

but I keep getting the error

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: rect is undefined

Comment: Since it's using codemirror, you might be able to do what you want via the codemirror API by executing some javascript. I also did a quick google search on "jupyter selenium" and got lots of results. Have you done any research to see how others are doing it?

Comment: I couldn't find any examples of others doing. Could you share some examples? It would be greatly preferable to be able to do this all from python though as that's where all our other tests are.

Comment: @BryanOakley this looks promising but still gives me an error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48969245/1011724

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I'm not sure what from that accepted answer I'm not already doing (also, I link to it in my question)? Could you explain it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code below tested with Chrome, Firefox and jupyterlab latest versions:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("http://localhost:8888")
token = "0107216930d05db8a7c36ad6a73573dd5349c3dd56fee852"

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "password_input"))).send_keys(token, Keys.ENTER)

# wait for "Python 3" Notebook menu or CodeMirror element if already launched.
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[title='Python 3'][data-category='Notebook'], .jp-Notebook .CodeMirror")))
# if "Python 3" Notebook menu found click to open new Notebook
if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[title='Python 3'][data-category='Notebook']")) > 0:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[title='Python 3'][data-category='Notebook']").click()

# wait for CodeMirror and click to focus
code_mirror = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".jp-Notebook .CodeMirror")))
code_mirror.click()
code_mirror.find_element_by_tag_name("textarea").send_keys("print('Hello World!')")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[data-icon='run']").click()

output = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".jp-OutputArea-output")))
print(output.text)
assert output.text.strip() == "Hello World!"

driver.quit()
```

Comment: *"In Files tab click on "New" menu and select "Python 3", new window will be opened"* this sounds like you're using jupyter notebook instead of jupyterlab?

Comment: Let me check jupyterlab

Comment: Cool, thanks :) in lab `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".jp-Launcher-cwd+ .jp-Launcher-section .jp-LauncherCard").click()` should work to create a new notebook

Comment: Check update code for the jupyterlab, tested with new and launched notebooks

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Can I ask how you figured out the selectors and the order to use them in? i.e. why `".jp-Notebook .CodeMirror"` and then why `"textarea"` by tag? Also why `presence_of_element_located` instead of `presence_of_element_clickable`?

Comment: Also, just storing this here for myself for the future, but instead of clicking the run button this also works `ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys(Keys.RETURN).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()` to execute a cell.

Comment: I used in for the `.jp-Notebook .CodeMirror textarea` because wait clickable throw an error, reason is `textarea`. Later I used `.jp-Notebook .CodeMirror`separate for click and with `textarea` send keys. But correct way is to use `element_to_be_clickable`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201552/discussion-between-sers-and-dan).

Answer (score 2):

**To Open Jupyter-Notebook:**

Either Open a command window and navigate to the repository folder or Open `anaconda-command-prompt` window and simply execute

- `jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.token='' --NotebookApp.password=''`

After loading notebook using `driver.get("http://localhost:8888")`, Here is the most tricky part, that how to select a `Dynamically changing object`. Visit Reference: [Dynamically Changing IDs](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18342/how-to-handle-dynamic-changing-ids-in-xpath).

> - By using  `find_element_by_xpath`
> - By using  `find_element_by_css_selector`

These both will give you the same selection-point but it would be better to use Xpath which is more convenient technique. You can move forward like this;

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.maximize_window()
website_url = "http://localhost:8888/"
driver.get(website_url)

# Using Xpath
# I prefer using xpath, because it is simple to understand
# and if you want to dynamically enter data into fields, it would be an awesome approach
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='new-buttons']").click()

if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='new-buttons']//li[@id='kernel-python3']")) > 0:

   time.sleep(3)
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='new-buttons']//li[@id='kernel-python3']").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="cell code_cell rendered selected"]').click()

# Using css_selector
#driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#notebook-container > div").click()

command = 'print("Hello World!")'

#a = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#notebook-container > div > div.input > div.inner_cell >"
#                                         "div.input_area > div > div:nth-child(1) > textarea")

time.sleep(3)
# To select Note-Book text-area and place command in it.
a = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="input_area"]//textarea').click().send_keys(command)

# To run the Code in Selected Cell
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title='Run']").click()

print("Test is done.")
```

Comment: All of these selectors give me `Unable to locate element` errors.

Comment: Also, why not just install geckodriver directly `brew install geckodriver` and then do `driver = webdriver.FireFox()`? Is there an advantage to your more verbose method?

Comment: Also *"Now move to Jupyter-python3 web-page, and rename Note-Book e.g Hello Test. After that delete all the available code cells which are already containing the code, it is because jupyter instance automatically save last instances sometimes."* I can't do any manual steps, but I can be sure that this is a fresh environment with no notebook files. I already have managed to automate creating a notebook file in Selenium (code at the top of the question).

Comment: With Chrome: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#notebook-container > div"}
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.70)`

Comment: @Dan answer is now optimized by using **X-path** technique which is much better and easy to use. Don't miss to add `time interval e.g. time.sleep(3)`  before every operation, as this time interval would specify every step of selenium on jupyter-notebook